# In a jobs page Build history showing build completed but in jenkins home page in BuildExecutor Status showing that job is currently running

Tags: jenkins

In Jenkins dashboard, builld executor status showing build number 39 for job 'x' is progressing. In job 'x' build history, it is showing build number 39 completed , but build number 40 is pending!
Os:Cent os 64 bit
Java Version:1.7.0_11

Comment: Jenkins Version:1.523

Comment: maybe try re-install jenkins?

Comment: @RenjiniKR: Ever find a solution to this?  Hitting the same issue.